# What racing games run on Ubuntu?

Tags: games

I am new to ubuntu. I used to play Need for Speed titles on Windows.

What racing games run on ubuntu?

Comment: There are lots of them listed here : https://duskfire.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/racing-games-on-linux/

Answer (score 11):

well lets start with this, there's a bunch. You just have to Google to find more games. If you want to install your Need For Speed games on Ubuntu I would install [wine](http://www.winehq.org/) and/or [play On Linux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) where you can install windows based games.

If you would like racing games written for Ubuntu I would try:

- [Racer](http://racer.nl), which is a racing simulator. The latest version is for Ubuntu 7.10 so I would use the Windows version.
- [Super Tux Kart](http://supertuxkart.sourceforge.net/) which is like Mario Cart. It's available via the software center, or by terminal, `sudo apt-get install supertuxkart`
- [Musclear Online](http://www.musclecar-online.com/) it's a 2D/3D racing game where you can race your
  friends via there recorded times. So you play a game, post your time
  and then your friends can compete against that.
- [vDrift](http://vdrift.net/) is a racing simulator. to install [click here.](http://www.playdeb.net/install/vdrift)
- [Rigs of Rods](http://www.rigsofrods.com/content/) which is more of a vehicle simulator, where you can
  try a lot of different vehicles, like trucks, boats, planes, and a
  lot more! Unfortianlly you have to compile the game from source, check [this link](http://www.rigsofrods.com/wiki/pages/Compiling_Sources_under_Linux) for more info. There is a more modern Windows version.

**Steam**
I would install [Steam for Linux](http://steamcommunity.com/linux) and see what games are available there, there are better chances for finding up-to-date games, and games that you've seen before.

*Adding more when I find more...*

Answer (score 3):

TORCS (The Open Racing Car Simulator) seems to be the main one: http://torcs.sourceforge.net/

Installation:

Search for 'TORCS' in the Ubuntu Software Center (icon in the launcher) and click 'Install' or press the keys `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` and copypaste:

```
sudo apt-get install torcs
```

It is the most recent version in Ubuntu 12.10, 13.04 and 13.10.

To get the latest version in Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS and 12.04.3 LTS, use the install instructions here: http://torcs.sourceforge.net/index.php?name=Sections&op=viewarticle&artid=3#linux-lokiinstaller (This will not stay updated automatically and you will have to redownload and reinstall when they release a new version).

Comment: Some people still run it though.